# How to execute VBA(Excel) Macros using Python on AWS Lambda functions?

Tags: python, excel, vba, aws-lambda

The excel file is dropped in AWS S3 bucket. I want to write a lambda function that will pick the file from s3, execute the VBA macro script on it and store it back in different s3 location. I want to use Python to execute the macro script. I am able to do it on windows locally but I don't know how to do it using AWS lambda? Is it possible?

For executing it locally, my code looked like this,

```
import os, os.path
import win32com.client

if os.path.exists("test_macro.xlsm"):
    xl=win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    xl.Workbooks.Open(os.path.abspath("test_macro.xlsm"), ReadOnly=1)
    xl.Application.Run("test_macro.xlsm!Module2.test")
    wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(os.path.abspath("test_macro.xlsm"),ReadOnly=0)
    wb.Save()
    xl.Application.Quit()
    del xl
```